# Moose traits for multdimensional data structures

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, moose

Breaking out handling an internal variable from calls on the variable into calls on the object is easy using the Attribute::Native::Trait handlers. However, how do you deal with multiple data structures? I can't think of any way to handle something like the below without making the stash an arrayref of My::Stash::Attribute objects, which in turn contain an arrayref of My::Stash::Subattribute objects, which contains an arrayref My::Stash::Instance objects. This includes a lot of munging and coercing the data each level down the stack as I sort things out.

Yes, I can store the items as a flat array and then grep it on every read, but in a situation with frequent reads and that most calls are reads, grepping against a large list of array items is a lot of processing every read vs just indexing the items internally in the way needed.

Is there a MooseX extension that can handle this sort of thing via handlers creating methods, instead of just treating the read accessor as the hashref it is and modifying it in place? Or am I just best off forgetting about doing things like this via method call and just doing it as-is?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

package My::Stash;
use Moose;

has '_stash' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'HashRef', default => sub { {} });

sub add_item {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($item) = @_;

  push @{$self->_stash->{$item->{property}}{$item->{sub}}}, $item;
}

sub get_items {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($property, $subproperty) = @_;

  return @{$self->_stash->{$property}{$subproperty}};
}

package main;
use Data::Printer;

my $stash = My::Stash->new();

for my $property (qw/foo bar baz/) {
  for my $subproperty (qw/fazz fuzz/) {
    for my $instance (1 .. 2) {
      $stash->add_item({ property => $property, sub => $subproperty, instance => $instance })
    }
  }
}

p($_) for $stash->get_items(qw/baz fuzz/);
```

Answer (score 1):

These are very esoteric:

```
sub add_item {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($item) = @_;

  push @{$self->_stash->{$item->{property}}{$item->{sub}}}, $item;
}
```

So `add_item` takes an hashref `item`, and pushes it onto an array key in *stash* indexed by it's own keys `property`, and `sub`.

```
sub get_items {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($property, $subproperty) = @_;

  return @{$self->_stash->{$property}{$subproperty}};
}
```

Conversely, `get_item` takes two arguments, a `$property` and a `$subproperty` and it retrieves the appropriate elements in a Array in a HoH.

So here are the concerns into making it MooseX:

- There is no way in a non-Magic hash to insist that only hashes are values -- this would be required for predictable behavior on the trait. As in your example, what would you expect if `_stash->{$property}` resolved to a scalar.
- `add_item` has it's depth hardcoded to `property` and `sub`.
- returning arrays is bad, it requires all of the elements to be pushed onto the stack (return refs)

Now firstly, I don't see why a regular Moose Hash trait couldn't accept array refs for both the setter and getter.

```
->set( [qw/ key1 key2/], 'foo' )    
->get( [qw/ key1 key2/] )
```

This would certainly make your job easier, if your destination wasn't an array:

```
sub add_item {
   my ( $self, $hash ) = @_;
   $self->set( [ $hash->{property}, $hash->{subproperty} ], $hash );
}

# get items works as is, just pass in an `ArrayRef`
# ie, `->get([$property, $subproperty])`
```

When it comes to having the destination be an array than a hash slot, I assume you'd just have to build that into a totally different helper in the trait, `push_to_array_or_create([$property, $subproperty], $value)`. I'd still just retrieve it with the fictional `get` helper specified above. `auto_deref` type functionality is a pretty bad idea.

In short ask a core developer on what they would think about extending `set` and `get` in this context to accept *ArrayRefs* as keys and act appropriately. I can't imagine there is a useful default for ArrayRef keys (I don't think regular stringification would be too useful.).